# UIAutomation become slow after Windows 10 Creators Update (1703))

Tags: c++, com, ui-automation

Windows 10 (1607) - **ElementFromPoint** call duration near **2 ms**.

After Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) - **ElementFromPoint** call duration near **500ms**.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <UIAutomationClient.h>

IUIAutomation* g_automation = nullptr;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelMouseProc(INT nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    POINT pt = ((PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam)->pt;

    IUIAutomationElement *element = nullptr;
    g_automation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &element);

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

void main()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_SPEED_OVER_MEMORY);
    CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(CUIAutomation), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        __uuidof(IUIAutomation), (void**)& g_automation);

    SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, (HOOKPROC)LowLevelMouseProc, 
    GetModuleHandle(nullptr), 0);

    MSG message;
    GetMessage(&message, (HWND)NULL, 0, 0);
}
```

Point is mouse click coordinates.

Too long ElementFromPoint - this is issue.

Looks like some changed in COM/UIAutomation processing?

Is exist some workaround get UI element from point?

Comment: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/3135331/uiautomation-become-slow-after-windows-10-creators-update-1703